# Sending match from preg_replace to scandir inside function

Tags: php, preg-replace, scandir

I'm having issues using scandir with a variable sent through a function from preg_replace. I'm getting warning when I run the code `PHP Warning:  scandir(../dir/$1): failed to open dir: No such file or directory`, however, when I echo `$dir` it echos it correctly with $1 expanded to the variable. Here's my code:

```
$str = preg_replace('/([0-9]{2})/', $this->functionName("$1"), $str);

private function functionName($year) {
        $path = '../dir/'.$year;
        echo $path; // echos 'dir/14'
        $results = scandir($path); // claims $path is 'dir/$1'
}
```

Comment: You can't do it like that, the `"$1"` will not be replaced with the match. Look into `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: `claims $path is 'dir/$1'` -- Are you **sure**?

Comment: @AmalMurali According to that PHP Warning yes. The PHP Warning and the PHP echo give me controversial strings.

Comment: @Wrikken if that is the case when why is echo in the function echoing the correct path, or am I crazy and that shouldn't happen?

Comment: @michaellindahl: indeed, that echo shouldn't work ([and doesn't do that on any version I tested](http://3v4l.org/TTfrb))

Comment: ([neither with `echo` instead of `var_dump`](http://3v4l.org/oAYO8))

Comment: Oh damn, I think I know what's happening: do you mean you `return $path;`  and then it works, rather then actually `echo`? Because, that would result in `preg_replace` getting the _string_ `'path/$1'` in its second, parameter, in which it can then replace the `$i` with `14`. [is this more like you see it happening?](http://codepad.org/Xwi8LQE9)

Comment: @Wrikken yes, that is more like what is happening. $year when returned back in a larger string is correct, however when used in `scandir()` and error is thrown because it is '$1'.

Comment: Yes, which is exactly how it is supposed to work. (You supply a string `"$1"` to a function, `preg_replace` isn't going to reparse you entire PHP file to see what you do there, and override that argument. It will just know about the _return_  that function gives in its second parameter). So, `preg_replace_callback` seems to indeed be what you want instead.